# Custom ColumnChooser, how to update grid on saving

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am creating a custom column chooser for jqgrid. On selecting columns and saving, I get a set of columns as selected columns.

How to update the grid with selected columns, manually? Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy:

- you need to use `showHideCol` method (or `showCol` and `hideCol`) for showing/hiding the columns
- you should use `remapColumnsByName` method (or an old `remapColumns`) for changing the order of the columns. See [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/r6b2os5b/2/) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35452226/315935) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm) from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935).

Comment: I believe both ShowHideCol and rempaColumnsByName will refresh the grid automatically. Correct?

Comment: @RustinCohle: The methods are from jqGrid and the results of changes will be visible immediately after applying.